# align font in middle of textfield

Tags: html, css, forms

i have text field with jquery hinthow do i alighn the font to be in the middle. i have tried vertical-align: middle but does not work.

```
<style type="text/css">
#name { 
    border: 1px solid #c810ca;
    height: 27px;
}


input[type=text].hint{ 
color: #fff;
 font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "times new roman";
}

input[type=text]{
    font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
    font-family: "times new roman";
}
```

form textfield

```
<div id="name">

                 <input name="name" type="text" id="name" title="insert here"/>

               </div>
```

Comment: Did you change the question after you got your answer? You should create a new one, not completely change the one you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can just explicitly set the height and width of the input (in CSS). That will ensure it stays the same no matter what the font-size is.

Comment: Well, you've already got a CSS declaration going for `input[type=text]`. Just add `height: 24px;` and `width: 200px;` to the properties. Obviously, adjust the actual pixel values to whatever size you want.

Answer (score 0):

If write is a single line of text, you can use **line-height** for vertical-align:middle.
The text is centered when **line-height** and **height** are same height.
For examle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tMbQP/